# Javascript function parameter to String

Tags: javascript, string, object

I have a javascript function which takes a parameter, like:

```
function getSomething(cat,handler) {

      varURI = 'text'+cat;
      document.write('<p>'+varURI+'</p>');

    }
```

What I see in the output is:

```
text[object Object]
```

How do I get the real textual value of the Object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override the `toString` method of the object -and give your object a "textual value"-.

You are getting `"[object Object]"` because the inherited `Object.prototype.toString` method is being executed, for example:

```
var cat = {
  name: 'Kitten',
  toString: function () {
    return this.name + ' meow';
  }
};
```

This own `toString` method will be executed when you make any implicit to string conversion (like when you concatenate a string to it), e.g.:

```
console.log(cat+' text'); // "Kitten meow text"
```

Note: If you mean by "textual value" a "string representation" of the object, (e.g. listing property/value pairs), your function will need to enumerate all the properties (using the `for-in` statement), but usually most of the time, that's done for debugging purposes, if that's the case, I would recommend you to get a debugger (like Firebug), and use the `console.dir` method.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what `cat` is, but usually you use the `toString()` method.

```
function getSomething(cat,handler) {

  varURI = 'text'+cat.toString();
  document.write('<p>'+varURI+'</p>');

}
```

Comment: Actually, he's getting `"[object Object]"` because the object doesn't have an own `toString` method (it's executing the inherited one from `Object.prototype.toString`), calling `cat.toString();` without overriding it won't make any difference, e.g.: `console.log({}+'');` and `console.log({}.toString());` both produce `"[object Object]"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this:

```
function ObjectToString(input,KeysOnly) {
    var ret = [];
    if(KeysOnly) 
       for(var k in input) 
        ret[k] = input[k]; 
    else 
        for(var k in input) 
        ret.push(k);
    return ret.toString();
}

function getSomething(cat,handler) {

  varURI = 'text'+ObjectToString(cat);
  document.write('<p>'+varURI+'</p>');
}
```